# Delete the product in the cart, if the same product added in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

There are methods that empty the cart if you add a new product.

```
function wdm_empty_cart( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id ) 
{ 

global $woocommerce;
$woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
}
```

But what I want is only if you add the same product. So adding  `if ( $in_cart )` does the job but I also do not want to empty whole cart.

Just want to delete the same product that added previously and keep the others.

I mean overwrite.

Comment: Same product will add quantity. So you want 1 quantity only for this product ? There is option in the product settings.

Comment: Hi, Sorry did not add. I disabled quantity. It is a travel site so we do not want quantity.

Comment: Doesnt matter. If you want only one qty per product to be added you dont need to replace it just check that option and wont add more. But if the code bellow is fine with you go ahead :)

Comment: Yes but it wont add more. Bhautik's solution is the best for me. It will add the new one always. When people make mistake for choosing adult or child they will get error when entering birtdate in the checkout. and they will go back and change it and add one more time. So there will be new product which is corrected. I can also empty the cart but what if they did not choose adult ot child wrong but just entered wrong birth date. So they can still correct in the checkout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation` action hooks and check against products that are already in the cart. code will go in your active theme functions.php file.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'remove_cart_item_before_add_to_cart', 1, 3);
function remove_cart_item_before_add_to_cart($passed, $product_id, $quantity) {
    
    $already_in_cart = false;
    
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $key => $item ){
        // Check if the item is already is in cart.
        if( $item['product_id'] == $product_id ){
            $already_in_cart = true;
            $existing_product_key = $key;
            break;
        }
    }

    if( $already_in_cart  ){
        WC()->cart->remove_cart_item($existing_product_key);
    }
    
    return $passed;
}
```